# Returns false every time in C++

Tags: c++

I made a simple sequential search function, so as i'm testing it, if I put 25 into my search item it returns true, but the other numbers 90, 21 are always false and I can't understand why it's doing that.

```
int a[] = {25,90,21};
int searchItem = 90;

if(sequentialSearch(searchItem, a, 3) == 1)
{
     cout << "Found Item" << endl;
}
else
{
     cout << "Item Not Found" << endl;
}

bool sequentialSearch(int searchItem, int * a, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(searchItem == a[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have a problem like this it is useful to debug the code and you would quickly see that you never check more than the first item of your array.

Comment: Looks like homework, so you probably need to implement it properly. But in real life you should use `std::find` instead

Comment: Try stepping through the function line by line in the debugger. The error should become apparent quickly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you return false if your element is not at first position. Try this

```
bool sequentialSearch(int searchItem, int * a, int size)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        if(searchItem == a[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your for loop ends up only checking the first item, and then returning true or false.  You need to change your logic to do something like

```
for( . . . )
{
    if(searchItem == a[i]) return true;
}
return false;
```

This way it will test each item in the array and then return false if nothing found.